# merge pdf files a4 and letter linux

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf, merge, ghostscript

I am training to merge multiple files using `ghostscript`, nevertheless the problem arises because the pdf files are in different paper size.

So far, I've found this one command:

```
gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf [...] lastfile.pdf
```

With same paper size it works, otherwise it does not.

Any suggestion are welcome?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want all pages in the resulting document to have the same paper size? For that, you would need to resize the page of one of the two documents. [This question](https://superuser.com/a/440164/217553) deals with resizing one PDF using `ghostscript`.

Otherwise, just leave out the `-sPAPERSIZE` switch, so your command will look like:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf lastfile.pdf
```